# Bash - Loop through JSON array

Tags: windows, bash

This is how my input looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Description 1"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 1"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 1"
    }
    {
        "Description": "Description 2"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 2"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 2"
    }
    {
        "Description": "Description 3"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 3"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 3"
    }
    {
        "Description": "Description 4"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 4"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 4"
    }
    {
        "Description": "Description 5"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 5"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue "
    }
    {
        "Description": "Description 6"
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 6"
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 6"
    }
]
```

I need to loop through each object inside the array and fetch OutputKey and OutPutValue and use it in another function.

How do i loop through this array and get the desired values?

***I am using GitBash on Windows box.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) your JSON is invalid, this is a correct version (`input.json`) :

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Description 1",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 1",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 1"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 2",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 2",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 2"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 3",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 3",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 3"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 4",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 4",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 4"
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 5",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 5",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue "
    },
    {
        "Description": "Description 6",
        "OutputKey": "OutputKey 6",
        "OutputValue": "OutputValue 6"
    }
]
```

2) as far as [json](/questions/tagged/json) means *JavaScript Object Notation*, I use [js](/questions/tagged/js) with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) script :

```
#!/bin/bash

node<<EOF
var arr = $(cat input.json);
arr.forEach(function(el){ console.log(el.OutputKey + " " + el.OutputValue ); })
EOF
```

#### Output

```
OutputKey 1 OutputValue 1
OutputKey 2 OutputValue 2
OutputKey 3 OutputValue 3
OutputKey 4 OutputValue 4
OutputKey 5 OutputValue 
OutputKey 6 OutputValue 6
```

#### Note

- you can use [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) instead of [node](/questions/tagged/node) and the `print()` command instead of `console.log()` if you prefer
- you can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) too

Comment: The output i am receiving is from aws CLI.

Comment: Which command ? Look for app switchs, I'm pretty sure it can produce a valid JSON as well...

Comment: this is the command: `echo $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --profile myProfile --region us-east-1 --stack-name "myStack" --query 'Stacks[*].Outputs[*]' --output json)`

Comment: Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html, you have to define a valid JSON template

Comment: I am not defining the template. I already have stack created from the template. I am just trying to grab the output values from that stack.

Comment: documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html says `Outputs is a list` which i assume is an array in `JSON`

Comment: I will not do your requirement for you, but I was replying to your original question in details